# Reference an element later in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two images that you have to select one or the other and the class changes depending on which you select using `ng-click`. On proceeding to the next step, I make an object and store references to what was just selected:

```
$scope.cabinetDetails.cabinetType = {
    name: $scope.currentElement.obj.name,
    image: $scope.currentElement.obj.image,
    ref: $scope.currentElement
};
```

`$scope.currentElement` is whatever image I had selected and I would think I could later access it via: `$scope.cabinetDetails.cabinetType.ref`

Let's say I am on step two and I want to make a change to step one. I click my breadcrumb to go back and I see step one again (this works fine). **What I'd like to happen is the class changes to its selected state.**

On loading step one, I do this:

```
if ($scope.cabinetDetails.cabinetType != null)
{
    $scope.currentElement = $scope.cabinetDetails.cabinetType.ref;
}
```

I would imagine this would preselect the image I had before since my `ng-repeat` does a simple check in the `ng-class` portion:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in currentObject">
    <div class="img-select" ng-click="setActive(this)" ng-class="{itemSelected : isActive(this)}">
      <div align="center">
        <img ng-src="resources/images/aventos/{{obj.image}}" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-title">{{obj.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `isActive()` function is also rather simple:

```
$scope.isActive = function(element)
{
    return $scope.currentElement === element;
}
```

I've been trying to avoid posting a question but I can't seem to figure this one out. It's like my reference is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `this` keyword. `this` is not available to pass through from the template.

Instead of referencing elements, take a step back and reference the underlying item in the repeater. Try changing `this` to `obj` (the object in your `ng-repeat="obj in currentObject"`)

```
ng-click="setActive(obj)" ng-class="{itemSelected : isActive(obj)}
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem is see in you html template is use of `this` in multiple methods. `this` would refer to the current scope object of the `ng-repeat`.

Assuming you are iterating over a array, can you change this line

```
<div class="img-select" ng-click="setActive(this)" ng-class="{itemSelected : isActive(this)}">
```

to

```
<div class="img-select" ng-click="setActive(obj)" ng-class="{itemSelected : isActive(obj)}">
```

Also verify that the method `setActive` and `isActive` are working on your object instead of scope instance, by debugging the method.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I gave the check mark to the guy who answered it first. I have a feeling you both answered it around the same time, regardless, your solution works ;)